# How can I mount a single RAID 1 disk/partition as ext3?

Tags: linux, mount, raid-1, ext3

I need to copy data from a single HD, which used to be part of a Linux RAID 1. I've googled around, but can't find any clue how to mount partitions from this single HD.

Background: The HD comes from a linux based NAS box Synology DS207+. The NAS uses ext3 as filesystem. Both NAS disks are fine, but the other NAS hardware is dead and not worth repairing or replacing.

Comment: any idea how to do this on a Mac? I'll be needing an [Ext4 driver](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/) for sure, but is there anything else that need to do to mount the formerly RAID-1 drive?

Answer (score 0):

An important step is to have mdadm scan for the disk prior to attempting to mount anything:

```
mdadm --detail --scan
```

I can't recall from memory but the --assemble flag may be necessary but try the above first then try mounting via:

```
mount /dev/md# /path/to/mount
```

Comment: How to install `mdadm` to mac os x?

Comment: You might need to launch `mdadm --run /dev/md#` to start a partially assembled array

Comment: @skywinder `mdadm` in Linux is just a tool to control the Linux kernel software RAID subsystem, so it won't be useful in a Mac unless there is also a software RAID driver with a Linux-style API added to the Mac kernel - and such a thing might not exist.

Answer (score -1):

When you only have a single part of a Raid array, it is in an incomplete state and for safety reasons, you basically have to force mount it.

There are many linux distributions, for me, in Ubuntu, I used:

```
 mkdir /mnt/tempdisk
 sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/tempdisk -o force
```

(replace sda3 with the hard drive)

if a *nix expert wants to down vote me, I will delete my answer as it has been a few years since I did this, and I followed a guide at the time.

Comment: You don't have to force anything. Just mount the md device: "mount /dev/md1 /mnt/myfolder". The degraded array will run without any problem. But nothing garantee the Symbology use a standard Linux RAID.

Comment: Ext[234] has no "force" mount option, so this answer is nonsense.